# Need help in building efficient exhaustive search algorithm

Tags: algorithm, math, search, combinatorics

There are a 10 buttons. These buttons can unlock the lock if pressed in correct order (5 presses in sequence). Every button press triggers unlock check.

Example: "password" is 123456 and I press buttons 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 I unlock the lock from 6th button press.

I need to design algorithm that tries all possible combinations in the most efficient way (i.e. minimum amount of buttons should be pressed).

I can interpret button number as digit and number of pressed button in sequence as digit position and then try all 99999 combinations in attempt to unlock the lock but I feel that there is a more efficient algorithm to do that.

Is there something I can do to optimize this search?

Comment: Nope - exhaustive search is about searching all possibilities. Your solution seems to have no redundancy (no combination is checked twice) and is simple enough. The use of integer is also efficient.

Comment: One thing that might be an optimization, is dependent if for example 11223 is a valid combination. If it is not - you can try to trim numbers with repeating digits.

Comment: @amit 112233 is a valid combination.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To optimize a brute-force attack on a lock, you can use [De Bruijn sequences](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence).

> The sequence can be used to shorten a brute-force attack on a PIN-like code lock that does not have an "enter" key and accepts the last n digits entered. For example, a digital door lock with a 4-digit code would have B(10, 4) solutions, with length 10,000. Therefore, only at most 10,000 + 3 = 10,003 (as the solutions are cyclic) presses are needed to open the lock. Trying all codes separately would require 4 × 10,000 = 40,000 presses.