# Optimal sequence to brute force solve a keypad code lock

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Need help in building efficient exhaustive search algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211425/need-help-in-building-efficient-exhaustive-search-algorithm)

Imagine that you must open a locked door by inputting the correct 4-digit code on a keypad. After every keypress the lock evaluates the sequence of the last 4 digits inputted, *i.e.* by entering `123456` you have evaluated 3 codes: `1234`, `2345` and `3456`.

- What is the shortest sequence of keypresses to evaluate all `10^4` different combinations?
- Is there a method for traversing the entire space easy enough for a human to follow?

I have pondered this from time to time since a friend of mine had to brute force such a lock, to not having to spend the night outdoors in wintertime.

---

#### My feeble attempts at wrapping my head around it

With a code of length `L=4` digits and an "alphabet" of digits of size `D=10` the length of the optimal sequence cannot be shorter than `D^L + L - 1`. In simulations of smaller size than `[L,D] = [4,10]` I have obtained optimal results by semi-randomly searching the space. However I do not know if a solution exists for an arbitrary `[L,D]` pair and would not be able to remember the solution if I ever had to use it.

#### Lessons learned so far

When planning to spend the night at a friends house in another town, be sure to not arrive at 1 am if that person is going out to party and won't hear her cell phone.

Comment: @DanW Yes, there are two questions. Downvoters, why?

Comment: +1 both for the question and because I've been in the same situation once :)

Comment: Your first question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12211425/1009831).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Obviously this has happened to people before so I figured SO would crack it.

Comment: Look for which 4 keys on the keypad are most worn. Then brute force in 24 attempts ;-)

Comment: Yes, that would reduce the expected time tremendously. Also, try all combinations that include the house number. Landlords, janitors etc. don't like to remember a lot of codes and often use rules like "##16" where ## is house number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The link Evgeny provided should answer both of your quests. This answer is a bit offtopic, but you ask for a solution for humans.

In the real world you should probably rely more on [Social engineering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_engineering_%28security%29) or [heuristics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic), and after that on mathematics. I give a case on real life:

I went to visit an apartment and I found out that my cellphone was dead. Now way of contacting the person doing the visit. I was about to go back when I saw that the door used a keypad `0 - 9` and `A B`. I made several assumptions:

1. The code is 5 digits long. The length is pretty standard depending on the region you are in. I based this assumption on buildings I had access before (legally :D).
2. The code starts with numbers, then either `A` or `B` (based on my own building).
3. The keypad was not brand new. Conclusion, the numbers used in the code were a bit damaged. I knew with certainty which numbers were not in the code, and three of the four number in the code (given my previous assumptions)
4. By the amount of keys damaged I assumed the code didn't contain repeated keys (7 were damaged, it was clear `A` was used, `B` not used )

At the end I had 3 numbers which were in the code for sure, 2 candidates for the last number and I was sure `A` was at the end. On key was just slightly damaged compared to the others.

I just had to enumerate permutations starting with the candidate which seemed the more damaged, which give me `4! + 4! = 48` tries. Believe me, at the 5th try the door was opened. If I can give my 2 cents, the old `put a key and open the door` is still the most reliable method to restrict access to a building.

Comment: The "most reliable method to guarantee access to a building" is to not lock the door :)

Comment: Even keys only really work when there's no traffic. This fact doesn't help the questioner's 1am situation much, but as a general security measure shared locked doors only go so far. In practice the most common way that I have got into buildings is by hanging around until someone comes in or out. I went to university before everybody had cellphones, and it was fairly common to need to break into the place to get the attention of whoever you were visiting...

Answer (score 5):

I think you want a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn_sequence - "a cyclic sequence of a given alphabet A with size k for which every possible subsequence of length n in A appears as a sequence of consecutive characters exactly once."

Comment: Thanks! Although you answered what I asked, @UmNyobe answered what I meant :) so I have to stick with that. But I can give a +1 for the effort.